# Docker docker-compose multiple networks

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

Is possible to have a docker container with two networks in a docker-compose, one host and the other bridge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is absolutely possible to have two networks.

`services:
  redis: 
    networks:
      - my_network
      - bridge_networks`